# How to merge this PHP, Javascript and HTML document into one?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am attempting to upload a CSV file ONLY, using a HTML form, then using PHP and Javascript to save it in an array.

I have some code, that is working perfectly as separate files. Although, when I try to merge them into the one file, it refuses to work and the Javascript array ends up just alerting as  `null`.

I am trying to only call the PHP if the form has been posted, and then calling the Javascript only when the submit button has been pressed.

**The separated version - WORKING**

*The HTML*

```
<form action="yourscript.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="upload_file" />
 <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

*The Javascript and PHP*

```
<?php
$csv_array = Array();
$file = fopen($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
if($file){
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
      //$line is an array of the csv elements
      array_push($csv_array,$line);
    }
    fclose($file);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>var your_array = <?php echo json_encode($csv_array); ?></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**The merged version - NOT WORKING**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['savecsv']))
{
    $csv_array = Array();
    $file = fopen($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
    if($file)
    {
        while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) 
        {
            //$line is an array of the csv elements
            array_push($csv_array,$line);
        }
        fclose($file);
    }
}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
    function saveArray()
    {
        var your_array = <?php echo json_encode($csv_array); ?>

        alert(your_array);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="upload_file" />
 <input type="submit" name="savecsv" onClick="saveArray();"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> should have an echo

Comment: And also use **htmlspecialchars** on **$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']**

Comment: Another approach is to use the new Javascript [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to read the CSV file into a string on the browser and parse to an array, without all the back and forth. [Needs a newer browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader) -- I also have an early working version of a  library that uses FileReader and a few other tricks to manipulate and analyze CSV format data in the browser. [html5csv](https://github.com/DrPaulBrewer/html5csv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's failing because `onclick` fires when you click the button, *before* the forms submits to the server. In order for this to work, you need to submit the form to the server. You can do this with a true form submission (which will reload the page), you can submit the form into an `<iframe>`, or you can use AJAX to submit the form.

The first time the page loads, of course `your_array` is null because no file was uploaded. When the `onclick` fires (before the form is submitted), it simply alerts this null value from the initial page load.

To make your current solution work (reloading the whole page), trigger the JavaScript from inside the PHP code instead of `onclick`:

```
<?php
if (isset($csv_array)) {
    $json = json_encode($csv_array);
    echo <<<HTML
    <script>
        var your_array = $json;
        alert(your_array);
    </script>
HTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Really?You can just put the whole html form into a variable then when the user visits the page,php checks if the form is submited.If it is submitted,it does nothing but instead it leaves the rest to javascript.If it is not submitted,it displays the form that is in the variable and halts the execution of the script.This way,you dont have to remove onclick or all the other cool stuff you got there.

```
 <html>
 <?php $form=<form>...</form>;
 if (!isset($_GET['submit']))
{die ("$form");} 

<script>...</script>
</html>
```

This way your javascript will not be executed unless the form is submitted.